# Converting MS Word File to PDF and then converting to CMYK PDF for Offset Printing

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, ghostscript, pdfcreator

I am a newbie to the knowledge of offset printing, what I am trying to do is to use MS Word 2007 to create a document containing both words and scanned images, and then use the PDFCreator software to convert the Word file as a PDF. Knowing that Word only supports RGB image, and the converted PDF file is also RGB, I then use Ghostscript to convert the PDF (`infile.pdf`) to become a CMYK PDF (`outfile.pdf`) with the following command:

```
gswin64c.exe -o outfile.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK infile.pdf
```

Now I get a CMYK PDF (`outfile.pdf`), but is it ready for offset printing? The colors in the CMYK PDF looks alright on the monitor, but will there be big changes on the printout? Is there anything (like settings and the Ghostscript command option) I need to pay attention to? Do I need to  convert the PDF as a PDF/X, PDF/X1 or even PDF/X4 file, (as I have read from various webpages on the Internet)?

Comment: You'd be far better off using a program that "understands" colour, such as InDesign. Do not expect accurate colour from Word, no matter what contortions you go through. The problem is that the PDF created by Word does not have any information about device colour profiles, and hence the colours cannot be corrected between the monitor and printing press.